# rotating font-awesome glyphicon on ajax call

Tags: ajax

i have ajax code below

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shoppingcart_service.asmx/RegisterSubscriber",
            data: "email=" + SubscriberEmail, // the data in form-encoded format, ie as it would appear on a querystring
            //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", // if you are using form encoding, this is default so you don't need to supply it
            dataType: "text", // the data type we want back, so text.  The data will come wrapped in xml
            success: function (data) {
                $("#searchresultsA").html(data); // show the string that was returned, this will be the data inside the xml wrapper
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

how do i add an onbegin function to begin spining the button that calls this function, and end it using onend ajax function,

i am using font-awesome as gylphicon (http://fontawesome.info/website-lists-and-examples-using-font-awesome-icon-css/fa-arrow-circle-right), and i need to show the rotating

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-2x fa-spin"></i> when call begins, there by replacing
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
```

here is the buttons' html

```
 <a href="#"  class="btn btn-warning  btn-block"   id="btnSave" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></i>Subscribe</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Example uses the `jQuery JavaScript library`.

First, create an Ajax icon using the [AjaxLoad site](http://www.ajaxload.info/).

Then add the following to your HTML:

```
<img src="/images/loading.gif" id="loading-indicator" style="display:none" />
```

And the following to your CSS file:

```
#loading-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Lastly, you need to hook into the Ajax events that jQuery provides; one event handler for when the Ajax request begins, and one for when it ends:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
  $('#loading-indicator').show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
  $('#loading-indicator').hide();
});
```

Taken from [source](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/204-how-to-display-an-animated-icon-during-ajax-request-processing).

Comment: how does it answer his question about font-awesome?

Answer (score 2):

#### One Liner

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
```

More of it [here](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#animated).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as in FA docs

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
```